# How to get the data and the amount of data simultaneously

Tags: mysql

This query would get one row with the id and the number of ID in the Messages.

```
SELECT id, count (id) FROM Messages
```

and I need that could get a list of id in the second field was the number

EDIT:

I do paged media.
To do this I need to know how many of these lines that would make the button "next" active or not active

I used C#

Comment: Your example query is not deterministic. What are you actually trying to do? Select the first row? If so, what do you mean by first?

Comment: "I need that could get a list of id in the second field was the number" Can you clarify this a bit more? Maybe an example of what output you are expecting might be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get both the id of the first row number and the overall count of rows in a single row of data, so you don't have to either do two queries or run a query returning a lot of rows just for the purpose of finding out how many rows it returns.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(id), COUNT(id) AS count
  FROM Messages
```

or, if you want the first batch of data rows matching some criterio along with the count you could try something like this:

```
SELECT detail.id, detail.message_text, detail.user, summary.count
  FROM (SELECT id, message_text, user
          FROM Messages
         WHERE user = 'user'
         ORDER BY id ASC) detail
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) count
          FROM Messages
         WHERE user = 'user') summary
  LIMIT by 0,10
```

If you put indexes on your `user` and `id` columns this query will be decently efficient.  All the rows will have the same value for summary.count, which is the number you want to control your next-page button's visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want the total number of columns?  If that's the case and you're using php, you can call mysql_num_rows on the query result; there's probably something similar for other platforms.